# Using indexing in XPath

Tags: xpath, indexing, expression, using

I have a following fragment of XML:

```
<ul>
<li>xxx
    <ul> enter code here
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>yyy
    <ul>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

and my `XPath`

```
(//ul[@class="some-class"][1]//li)[1]
```

returns as expected `xxx`, `1`, and `2`. But when I use

```
(//ul[@class="some-class"][1]//li)[2]
```

it returns starting from `1`, not `yyy` as I expect. Please advise.

Comment: Update your `xml` sample as there is no `ul` element with `class="some-class"` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Try the XPath

```
//ul[@class='some-class'][1]/li[2]//text()[1]
```

It gives

```
yyy
        34
```

as output.
How to handle the spaces is another thing...

Answer (score 0):

```
(//ul[@class="some-class"][1]//li)[1]
```

when you use `//li`, this means all the descent of ul tag.

```
<ul>
<li>xxx             # the 1st li tag
    <ul> enter code here 
        <li>1</li>  # the 2st li tag
        <li>2</li>  # the 3st li tag
    </ul>
</li>
<li>yyy             # the 4st li tag
    <ul>
        <li>3</li>  # the 5st li tag
        <li>4</li>  # the 6st li tag
    </ul>
</li>
```

you should use `(//ul[@class="some-class"][1]/li)[1]`

`/li` means the child of ul tag.

```
    <ul>
<li>xxx             # the 1st li tag
    <ul> enter code here 
        <li>1</li>  
        <li>2</li>  
    </ul>
</li>
<li>yyy             # the 2st li tag
    <ul>
        <li>3</li>  
        <li>4</li>  
    </ul>
</li>
```